# GTA 5 online for Xbox One

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have an Xbox One and when I try to use GTA online it says that my account does not have permission to access this feature. Do I need an Xbox LIVE membership/gold membership to use this?

Answer (score 2):

You must have an Xbox Live Gold membership to play GTA Online.

I can't find any official page to source for this answer, but it's considered common knowledge that multiplayer content in any Xbox game is locked behind a Gold subscription. There are also [multiple](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/634491-grand-theft-auto-v/67916635) [forums](http://gtaforums.com/topic/608595-is-xbox-gold-membership-required-in-order-to-play-gtaol/) where people ask this same question, and all replies confirm that a Gold subscription is necessary.